# Iterate over rows of astropy.table Table object

Tags: python, astropy

What is the smartest way to iterate over rows of a Table object from astropy.table?

Is it something like:

```
for row in table:
    ....
```

?

Comment: Did you try that? And if so did it work?  Why should there be any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterating over table rows works as expected:

```
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> table = Table([[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']])
>>> for row in table:
...     print row['col0'], row['col1']
...     
1 a
2 b
3 c
```